# Filter key in query params and there is parsing error in aws gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, serverless, serverless-framework

I am using serverless framework and recently changed to lambda integration from lambda proxy integration. Now I have one endpoint that uses filter in query params. And this is the request template I am using to map query strings,

```
"queryStringParameters": {
  #foreach($query in $request_query.keySet())
        "$query" : "$util.escapeJavaScript($request_query.get($query))"
        #if($foreach.hasNext),#end
        #end
      }
```

This is the endpoint:

`https://example.com/ds/districts?page=1&pagesize=12&filtercriteria=name~%27John%27`

But when I invoke this endpoint I am getting error

```
Could not parse request body into json: Could not parse payload into json: Unrecognized character escape \'\'\' (code 39)\n at [Source: (byte[])\"
```

These are the docs I am referring,

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-mapping-template-reference.html#util-template-reference

https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/events/apigateway#lambda-integration

Any help or suggestion is greatly appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 0):

As per the Documentation $util.urlDecode()and passing each query element into this solved the problem.